# What is the purpose of %config IPCompleter.greedy = True?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, config

I am kinda learning ML. Just can across these command

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy = True
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

I was able to search get results related to these on web but wasn't able to find its purpose. If any one can share some info or to any docs on  these will be helpful... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `%config IPCompleter` from inside ipython for a list and description of the available options. Note that `greedy` is deprecated, but I'm attaching its description for reference below:

```
IPCompleter.greedy=<Bool>
    Activate greedy completion PENDING DEPRECTION. this is now mostly taken care
    of with Jedi.
    This will enable completion on elements of lists, results of function calls,
    etc., but can be unsafe because the code is actually evaluated on TAB.
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "This will enable completion on elements of lists" please?